# Android simple game. Add imagebuttons on game-view

Tags: java, android

Is there away to put buttons/imagebuttons on top of the "game-surface"?
I'm experimenting with code from this blog:
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-game-development-tutorial-1/

I need to change direction for objects on the screen with some buttons.
In the tutorial a ship changes direction if the touch screen is pressed anywhere.

I have tried this:
ImageButton b1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.turn_left);
in order to add the button later to the view with addView, but it returns null.
Maybe becaue setContentView(gameView); set the view of GameView and not
GameActivity?
Any suggestions on how to make this work?

```
public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private GameView gameView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Getting display object
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

    //Getting the screen resolution into point object
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);

    gameView = new GameView(this, size.x, size.y);

    //adding it to contentview
    setContentView(gameView);
}
```

GameView

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable { 
     ...code...
     private void draw() {

    //checking if surface is valid
    if (surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
        //locking the canvas
        canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        //drawing a background color for canvas
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        //Drawing the player
        canvas.drawBitmap(
                ...code...
                draw);
        //Unlocking the canvas
        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
}
....code....
 @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
         ...code...
    return true;
    }
}
```

XML

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="package.GameActivity">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/turn_left"
    android:background="@drawable/left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom button class which draw bitmap through canvas.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure what you mean by "draw bitmap through canvas"?

Comment: Create class having two bitmap pressed and unpressed for button and draw when touch pressed using canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapPressed,rect); and unpressed after touch up draw canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapunPressed,rect);